# How to find out the IP of my DD-WRT router working as a bridge

Tags: networking, ip, dd-wrt

I'm using my dd-wrt router as a bridge to be able to connect a computer that doesn't have a wifi card to be able to connect wireless by connecting that computer to the dd-wrt router with a cable  and then the router to the gateway wireless router.

My problem here is that I wanted to get into the configuration of the dd-wrt router so I typed 192.168.1.1 in the address bar and I get the configuration page of the gateway router not my dd-wrt router, to be able to know the ip address of my dd-wrt router I executed traceroute to see what's the next hop in the traffic and I got 192.168.1.1. I thought the next hop was going to be the dd-WRT router not the internet gateway.

So I'm not sure how can I know the ip address of my dd-wrt router. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you just forget the IP address of the bridge, or have you accidentally configured both routers to use 192.168.1.1? Also, bridges are by definition transparent to IP traffic, so they will never show up in a traceroute.

Comment: I would disconnect the WAN (switch off your WiFi) to break the bridge and brute force try every address.  Assuming you didn't change the subnet then your dd-wrt router will be on 192.168.1.x so you've only got to test 254 addresses from 192.158.1.1 to 192.168.1.254.  It really shouldn't take more than 30 minutes.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I was able to find out the IP by just running a IP scan with nmap, and I didn't have to switch off any WiFi (not sure why you suggested that), but I was able to just do a scan on the same subnet as my router is and voila, it took less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @TooTea No, I think if I had done that I wouldn't be able to use my bridge at all because it would cause an IP conflict. I didn't know that bridges were transparent to IP traffic. Now it makes sense.

Comment: @VaTo under the circumstances you described it made sense to switch off the WAN in case there was genuinely an IP conflict.  But if there was no conflict then it's not necessary.